# Access background image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently turning a HTML page into a WordPress theme. Throughout the site I have a series of `divs` that use CSS backgrounds. What is the best practice for linking those images, so the user can change them as they please?

For reference, in the HTML, I have: `background-image:url(/site/sprite.png);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom fields. If you don't know how to make them or you want an easy and robust way to manage them you can find the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin in the wordpress.org plugin repository. It's free and it's very nice.

The way you would use custom fields here is because you will set those backgrounds with inline style to your theme. Otherwise "the user" will have to know how to change a CSS line of code (not very practical).

If you set them inline they would look something like this:

```
<div id="divBackground01" style="background: url(<?php echo get_post_meta('$post->ID','div-bg-01',true); ?>);>

</div>
```

Another option that I've seen people do is make the CSS file in a PHP file... you would use something like:

```
<style>
  #divBackground01 {
    background: url(<?php echo get_post_meta('$post->ID','div-bg-01',true); ?>);
  }
</style>
```

Note that it's using PHP because the file would actually be a PHP file... otherwise you can't use PHP in a CSS file. Not sure that it's a very good practice to do this, but it's something doable as another option if you want.

Best to stick with adding the background style inline with the custom field. You can use PHP to make it conditional if needed and you can probably setup 1 post (so you have single ID) with all the custom fields... or whatever way you would prefer to present it to the user is your choice.

Comment: That's really great advice, thanks. Do you know of a method that could pull the images, but not make them editable? So the images were hardcoded within the theme?

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you want... but if you didn't use a custom field for it you could simply "hard code it" to your theme and if the user doesn't edit the theme's CSS then it shouldn't be a problem. If I didn't answer properly then maybe I'm not getting the gist of what you need, perhaps if you tell me what "pull the images" means for you then your comment above will make more sense. Run me by your user story and I'll give you my best advice on it.

Comment: Ah, I've just hard-coded now. I don't think I quite understood myself. Thanks for your help.